# I need a way to take some json and convert it to xml using node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, rss

On my node.js server I have some JSON that I need to convert to an RSS feed. What is the best way to do this? After doing the conversion it will need to output/overwrite an RSS file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

consider using https://github.com/dylang/node-rss

example:

`test.json`:

```
{
  "title": "foo",
  "description": "bar",
  "author": "hello"
}
```

`test.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , RSS = require('rss');

fs.readFile('test.json', function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    feed = new RSS(JSON.parse(data));
    fs.writeFile('feed.xml', feed.xml());
  }
});
```

run `node test.js` will generate the `feed.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title> <![CDATA[foo]]></title>
    <description><![CDATA[bar]]></description>
    <link>http://github.com/dylan/node-rss</link>
    <generator>NodeJS RSS Module</generator>
    <lastBuildDate>Fri, 13 Jan 2012 03:44:22 GMT</lastBuildDate>
  </channel>
</rss>
```